# Calling multiple jQuery functions in an ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, coding-style

I have a page with three HTML labels and their corresponding ASP.NET gridviews contained within divs. Now while learning jQuery, I am trying to achieve two things:
1. Change the css class of the lables upon mouse hover/out.
2. Slide up/down the grid div upon clicking of the labels.
It looks to be working as expected, but I wish to know if I am doing it the right way.

My complete jQuery code is:

```
$(function ColorChange(ID) {            
                $("#" + ID).toggleClass("gridLabel");
});
$(function ShowHide(GID) { 
                $('#' + GID).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

And I am calling these function from onmouseover, onmouseout and onclick events of the label controls passing in the label ID as parameter. As an example:

```
<label id="lblWebComp" class="gridLabelDefault" onmouseover="ColorChange('lblWebComp')"
                onmouseout="ColorChange('lblWebComp')" onclick="ShowHide('gvDivWC')">
                Web Components
</label>
```

Kindly let me know if this is the best way to achieve these effects? Don't I have to right the document ready function in the jQuery code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where are the MouseOver functions ? I am asking because maybe in this functions need some improvements. I see here that you always ask for the ID of your control, this is mean that you spend a lot of time searching the html-tree.

Comment: ^^ Updated question with the markup, hope that clarifies..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard jQuery style is to bind all your functions from jQuery in document ready, as you kinda guessed already in your question.

So instead of

```
<label id="lblWebComp" class="gridLabelDefault" onmouseover="ColorChange('lblWebComp')"
                onmouseout="ColorChange('lblWebComp')" onclick="ShowHide('gvDivWC')">
```

in the html markup you might have simply

```
<label class="gridLabelDefault">
```

and then in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gridLabelDefault').click(function() { // this assigns the click to all elements with gridLabelDefault class
        // here you want to find which grid the clicked label corresponds to, as an example
        // I've used siblings, which you could use if your elements are within a shared parent div
        $(this).siblings('.grid').slideToggle('slow'); // assuming you grid has a 'grid' class
    });
});
```

That should hopefully give you an idea of the kind of code structure you should be aiming for, obviously you will need to tweak it to your requirements. The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) is generally pretty good.

Regarding the css toggle, I don't really see from your example what benefits doing that in jQuery gives you. Just use the `hover` selector and do it in your css file. If you really want to use jQuery though, you can bind to the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event in document ready in the same manner as I showed with the click event above.

```
$('.gridLabelDefault').hover(
    function () { // this is the mouseOver function
        $(this).addClass('gridLabel');
    }, 
    function () { // this is the mouseOut function
        $(this).removeClass('gridLabel');
    }
);
```